# How to initialize private blockchain using flu?

Tags: private-blockchain, cpp-ethereum

I get the following error when trying to initialize a private bockchain using `flu`:

```
$ sudo flu console --config ~/ppaconfig.json
flu Hinted genesis block's state root hash is incorrect!
flu Hinted #56e81f17… , computed #40cf4430
```

The file `~/ppaconfig.json` is populated as shown below:

I got the enode hash string i.e. `enode://a14a17d85485f2cf9d27195e76775404058861c5c71c8c6d8a994d7f9892b6d1fe5f2129146ec168a776d72cf323a42a9f5c6746055e51870e281419b3a212f@81.141.218.136:5090`

... by running: `eth console`

Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
  "sealEngine": "BasicAuthority",
  "options": {
    "authorities": [
      "0x234496cc800e6e5ce4c8d9e1ff587afc031295be"
    ]
  },
  "params": {
    "accountStartNonce": "0x",
    "maximumExtraDataSize": "0x1000000",
    "blockReward": "0x",
    "registrar": "",
    "networkID" : "0x45"
  },
  "genesis": {
    "author": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "timestamp": "0x00",
    "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
    "extraData": "0x",
    "gasLimit": "0x1000000000000"
  },
  "accounts": {
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000001": { "wei": "1", "precompiled": { "name": "ecrecover", "linear": { "base": 3000, "word": 0 } } },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000002": { "wei": "1", "precompiled": { "name": "sha256", "linear": { "base": 60, "word": 12 } } },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000003": { "wei": "1", "precompiled": { "name": "ripemd160", "linear": { "base": 600, "word": 120 } } },
    "0000000000000000000000000000000000000004": { "wei": "1", "precompiled": { "name": "identity", "linear": { "base": 15, "word": 3 } } }
  },
    "network": {
    "nodes": [
      "enode://a14a17d85485f2cf9d27195e76775404058861c5c71c8c6d8a994d7f989d2b6d1fe5f2129146ec168a776d72cf323a42a9f5c6746055e51870e281419b3a212f@81.141.218.136:5090"
    ]
  }
}
```